# After upgrading ubuntu 22.04 appears this message

Tags: upgrade

3 Not upgraded and the below message in terminal

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p7
I: (UUID=2b529f0a-4d6f-43c9-b4d0-63df59c59c0c)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

Comment: This mesage is only an info; nothing to concern.  the apt message could be related to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates

Answer (score 0):

The `3 Not upgraded` message is either due to [phased updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates) or if you have installed the optional hardware enablement kernel you can list the not upgraded packages with `apt list --upgradeable` and then optionally manually install these 3 not upgraded packages with a command of the form `sudo apt install package1 package2 package3`.

The `I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p7 I: (UUID=2b529f0a-4d6f-43c9-b4d0-63df59c59c0c) I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.` message is just a notification about what initramfs will attempt to do when Ubuntu is booting.

Comment: Thanks for responsiveness

Comment: @hosein If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.